# NSDictionary passed to NSOperation is null inside the invoked method

Tags: objective-c, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, nsinvocationoperation

I'm using the code below to pass multiple values to NSOperation.

I have defined an NSDictionary but I can't access on it (it returns always null) within the method called.

Below is my code to invoke the method

```
NSDictionary *params = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
@"key1", @"value1",
@"key2", @"value2",
nil];

NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(method:) object:params];
[queue addOperation:operation];
```

Here is my method definition

```
- (void) method: (NSDictionary *) params {
     NSLog(@"value1: %@", [[params objectForKey:@"key1"] stringValue]);
}
```

The method called *method* is called but the NSLog prints always null when I actually aspect to see *value1* as per my dictionary definition.

Am I missing something?

Tnx

Answer (score 2):

As the method name `initWithObjectsAndKeys` indicates, in your case, `@"key1"` is the value/object and `@"value1"` is the key. Also, there is no `stringValue` method in the `NSString` object. So, try:

```
NSLog(@"value1: %@", [params objectForKey:@"value1"]);
```